# Modify Protocols With Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, ajax, plugins, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have an idea for a chrome extension where I take a protocol, just for example, `helloworld://` and in the url bar you could do `helloworld://check this out` and i could have the plugin alert `"check this out"` or do some other complex AJAX stuff?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a custom, made up, protocol? Chrome Extensions only operate on http, https, file or ftp schemes.

Or if you want to register a keyword in the address bar you can try the still experimental omnibox extension API. Then all text entered after a certain keyword is forwarded to a function which can process it and return a result, or maybe trigger other events.

<s>http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.omnibox.html</s>

**Edit by Dan Atkinson**

The above URL is now a 404. In the interest of keeping this answer relevant, the new url is:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox.html